# Pseudo code algorithm for vertex coloring with only 2 colors

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, pseudocode

I have a vertex coloring problem that I understand intuitively but have trouble getting into pseudo code form (to better understand it) and then in order to implement it.

This is my progress on the pseudo code and what I have worked out so far:

---

**Input**: List with **n** vertices that are randomly connected by **m** edges.

**Algorithm**:
The goal is to assign the color **red** or **blue** to a vertex so that two vertices that are neighbors (connected by an edge) do not share the same color.

**Output**:

-True (if possible to solve with 2 colors) 
or

-False (if not possible to solve with 2 colors)

---

Now, intuitively you can easily see that this will always work unless 3 vertices are all neighbors with one another.
For example, the following example will not work since A has an edge with both B and C:

|---------|

A - B - C

But the example below will work, since we can give A and C the color red and B the color blue:

A - B - C

My problem is that I'm stuck trying to figure out how to translate this 2 coloring problem with vertices and edges into a conventional list representation (using pseudo code), and then solve it with a breadth first search or depth first search algorithm.

All feedback and suggestions are welcome and appreciated! Thank you!

Edit: Not really the same, since I'm looking for the pseudo code for a list representation of this problem. How do I store the the information of which neighbors a certain vertex has in a list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find if a graph is bipartite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30486784/how-to-find-if-a-graph-is-bipartite)

Comment: "Now, intuitively you can easily see that this will always work unless 3 vertices are all neighbors with one another" -- Consider a 5-vertex circle, or in general any odd-length cycle.

Comment: @NicoSchertler: I don't think the question is a duplicate of the one you link to, because the key insight needed here is *realising that these 2 problems are the same problem*.

Comment: Not really the same, since I'm looking for the pseudo code for a list representation of this problem. How do I store the the information of which neighbors a certain vertex has in a list?